# xml content not parsing

Tags: php, xml, curl

I have created a function to get xml content and below is function to get xml content. curl is enabled on the server.XMl is validated on online xml validator tool.

```
function curlToGetXmlContent($url)
{
    $xml_file_url = $url;
    $curl = curl_init(); 
    // Setup curl. 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL,"$xml_file_url"); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0); 
    
    $xml_file = curl_exec($curl);
    $err = curl_error($curl);
    
    curl_close($curl);
    
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($xml_file_url );
    if ($err) { 
        echo "cURL Error:" . $err;
    } else {
        return $xml->item;
    }  
}
```

Call function in the content

```
  $xmlContent = curlToGetXmlContent("https://example.com/abc.xml");
  foreach ($xmlContent as $content) {
        $var = $content->id.''. $content->title;
  }
```

below is the xml of abc.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<items>
  <item>
    <id>1</id>
    <title>Example title, example.</title>
  </item>
  <item>
    <id>2</id>
    <title>Example title -1, example.</title>
  </item>
  <item>
    <id>3</id>
    <title>Example title -2, example.</title>
  </item>
  <item>
    <id>4</id>
    <title>Example title -3, example.</title>
  </item>
  <item>
    <id>5</id>
    <title>Example title -4, example.</title>
  </item>
  <item>
    <id>6</id>
    <title>Example title -5, example.</title>
  </item>
  <item>
    <id>7</id>
    <title>Example title -5, example.</title>
  </item>
  <item>
    <id>8</id>
    <title>Example title -7, example.</title>
  </item>
  <item>
    <id>9</id>
    <title>Example title -8, example.</title>
  </item>
  <item>
    <id>10</id>
    <title>Example title -9, example.</title>
  </item>
  <item>
    <id>11</id>
    <title>Example title -10, example.</title>
  </item>
  <item>
    <id>12</id>
    <title>Example title -11, example.</title>
  </item>
  <item>
    <id>13</id>
    <title>Example title -12, example.</title>
  </item>
  <item>
    <id>14</id>
    <title>Example title -13, example.</title>
  </item>
  <item>
    <id>15</id>
    <title>Example title -14, example.</title>
  </item>
  <item>
    <id>16</id>
    <title>Example title -15, example.</title>
  </item>
  <item>
    <id>17</id>
    <title>Example title -16, example.</title>
  </item>
  <item>
    <id>18</id>
    <title>Example title -17, example.</title>
  </item>
  <item>
    <id>19</id>
    <title>Example title -18, example.</title>
  </item>
  <item>
    <id>20</id>
    <title>Example title -19, example.</title>
  </item>
  <item>
    <id>21</id>
    <title>Example title -20, example.</title>
  </item>
  <item>
    <id>22</id>
    <title>Example title -21, example.</title>
  </item>
  <item>
    <id>23</id>
    <title>Example title -22, example.</title>
  </item>
  <item>
    <id>25</id>
    <title>Example title -23, example.</title>
  </item>
  <item>
    <id>26</id>
    <title>Example title -24, example.</title>
  </item>
  <item>
    <id>27</id>
    <title>Example title -25, example.</title>
  </item>
  <item>
    <id>28</id>
    <title>Example title -26, example.</title>
  </item>
  <item>
    <id>29</id>
    <title>Example title -27, example.</title>
  </item>
  <item>
    <id>30</id>
    <title>Example title -28, example.</title>
  </item>
  <item>
    <id>31</id>
    <title>Example title -29, example.</title>
  </item>
</items>
```

I am not getting content id and title and getting warning :

```
1. Warning: Attempt to read property "item" on bool in curlToGetXmlContent()
```

I am not sure i missed and why i am getting warning with any data render in foreach

Comment: I don't think it's related to this error, but you shouldn't call `simplexml_load_string()` if there's a curl error. Move that call into the `else` block.

Comment: The error message shows `<!DOCTYPE HTML`, which isn't in the sample XML you show. So I don't think you're fetching the file you think you are.

Comment: I don’t see a property « items » being read in `curlToGetXmlContent`. Only « item ». Typo perhaps?

Comment: As Barmat commented, it is likely that your url is wrong. It might be a html page with a 404 Not Found error. Check the url you feed to the function, enter it in a browser to see what the server’s response is.

Comment: By the way, if you simply want to HTTP GET the file, you don't need to use curl, you can use `file_get_contents($url)` or possibly even `simplexml_load_file()` directly. PS: What Barmar said is a strong indication of where the problem is.

Comment: The reference to `<DOCTYPE HTML` could be because some ISPs, if they can't retrieve the resource you requested, "helpfully" substitute an HTML page that informs you of the error.

Comment: @MichaelKay If the request does not contain any information about the required content-type (as in this case), returning a friendly HTML error message is actually a sensible behaviour, as long as the response includes an appropriate status code and a correct Content-Type header to be used by the client.

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to be with the way you are loading the XML content and processing it in the curlToGetXmlContent function. Instead of passing $xml_file_url to the simplexml_load_string function, you should pass $xml_file, which contains the actual XML content fetched using cURL. Additionally, you need to use simplexml_load_string instead of simplexml_load_string, as the former loads XML from a string, while the latter attempts to load the XML from a file.

Here's the updated version of your function:

```
function curlToGetXmlContent($url)
{
    $xml_file_url = $url;
    $curl = curl_init(); 
    // Setup curl. 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL,"$xml_file_url"); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0); 
    
    $xml_file = curl_exec($curl);
    $err = curl_error($curl);
    
    curl_close($curl);
    
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($xml_file); // Use $xml_file instead of $xml_file_url
    if ($err) { 
        echo "cURL Error:" . $err;
    } else {
        return $xml->item;
    }  
}
```

With this change, your curlToGetXmlContent function should now correctly load the XML content and return the item elements as expected.

One additional suggestion is to change the return statement to return all items as an array instead of just a single item, especially since you are using a foreach loop in your calling code. Here's the updated return statement:

Now, in your calling code, the foreach loop should work correctly and not produce the warning:

```
$xmlContent = curlToGetXmlContent("https://example.com/abc.xml");
foreach ($xmlContent as $content) {
    $var = $content->id . ' ' . $content->title;
    echo $var . "<br>"; // Assuming you want to print the id and title for each item
}
```

Output:

```
1 Example title, example.
2 Example title -1, example.
3 Example title -2, example.
4 Example title -3, example.
5 Example title -4, example.
6 Example title -5, example.
7 Example title -5, example.
8 Example title -7, example.
9 Example title -8, example.
10 Example title -9, example.
11 Example title -10, example.
12 Example title -11, example.
13 Example title -12, example.
14 Example title -13, example.
15 Example title -14, example.
16 Example title -15, example.
17 Example title -16, example.
18 Example title -17, example.
19 Example title -18, example.
20 Example title -19, example.
21 Example title -20, example.
22 Example title -21, example.
23 Example title -22, example.
25 Example title -23, example.
26 Example title -24, example.
27 Example title -25, example.
28 Example title -26, example.
29 Example title -27, example.
30 Example title -28, example.
31 Example title -29, example.
```